# Export/Import Macros to/from Nox APP Player (Android Emulator)

Tags: macros, emulator

I am using [Nox APP Player](http://en.bignox.com/) (3.7.0.0) on Windows 7 to run Android Applications. Nox includes a Macro Recorder, I try to figure out how to export and import saved macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Export:**
Macros are stored as simple text files at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Nox\record`.
To locate the macro you want to export, open `records` in your favorite text editor, locate the section that contains the name of the macro you want to export.

If you want to export the macro named `MACRONAME`, search for the corresponding entry in the `records` file:

```
...
    "7d13533fc95a7aeb46c3d794d500612a": {
    "name": "MACRONAME",
    "new": "false",
    "playSet": {
        "accelerator": "1",
        "interval": "0",
        "mode": "0",
        "playSeconds": "0#0#0",
        "repeatTimes": "1"
    },
    "time": "1578127486"
},
...
```

For this example, to export the macro, copy the file named `7d13533fc95a7aeb46c3d794d500612a` and the related section from the file named `records`.

**Import:**
To import a macro, quit Nox, simply copy the macro file to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Nox\record`. Open the `records` file and add the earlier saved section.

Start Nox, the added macro shows up in the Macro Recorder.